# Jquery flugin - how to get the main element in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

In this code, only the "test" in added to the class "team-member", probably because the second this is the function and not the element.
How can I do something of the main element(class) "team-member"  inside a function ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.team-member').SimpleSlider();
});


(function ($) {
    $.fn.SimpleSlider = function (options) {

        Initial();
        $(this).addClass("test");

        function Initial() {
             $(this).addClass("test2");
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: create a JSFiddle. Your current code is incomplete and the scope within the "initial" function is used incorrectly. Besides that: this question can easily be answered by reading any of the many plugin tutorials and examples for jquery plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, pass "this" as a parameter

```
$.fn.SimpleSlider = function (options) {


    Initial(this);
    $(this).addClass("test");

    function Initial(obj) {
         $(obj).addClass("test2");


 }
```